# Azure DevOps Services - Backup of Cl

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-services

Am using the cloud hosted version of Azure Devops (Azure DevOps Services).

How can i make a backup of all my repos, boards, artifacts and pipelines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no native tools to achieve this. Microsoft has long article about data protection in regards of Azure DevOps - link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/data-protection?view=azure-devops)

There is open source tools to backup repositories - link [here](https://github.com/lionelpere/azure-devops-repository-backup)

If you need something more complete. - there is a paid [solution](https://backrightup.com/)

I'm not related to any of these solutions.

Comment: Could you consider upvoting my reply if it was helpful?